# What's the difference between posting from a form and posting from a server?

Tags: php, node.js, http

On a php-server I capture all posted variables from $_POST, forexample

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

This works fine if I use a html-form to post to the server.

I try to post to the server using nodejs and requestify:

```
requestify.post('http://localhost/rest/1/comment/create', {hello: 'world'})
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.getBody());
})
```

This will not be captured by the php-server and var_dump($_POST) outputs an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit an HTML form, the data will be encoded using the  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (unless you tell it to use `text/plain` or `multipart/form-data`).

PHP will automatically parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` into `$_POST`.

Restify will encode data as `application/json`, which PHP won't parse by default. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19007851/19068) details how to read JSON formatted POST requests.

Comment: nice! Wich would be concidered better practice: to post the data in x-www-form-urlencoded from node or deal with it in the php?

Comment: @Himmators — That's very much a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);` snippet to read json request from PHP. `php://input` is PHP's STDIN where raw request is available. Details also available in [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).